# Terraform local-exec Provisioner to run on multiple Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, ansible, cloud, terraform

I had a working TF setup to spin up multiple Linux VMs in Azure. I was running a local-exec provisioner in a null_resource to execute an Ansible playbook. I was extracting the private IP addresses from the TF state file. The state file was stored locally.

I have recently configured Azure backend and now the state file is stored in a storage account.

I have modified the local provisioner and am trying to obtain all the private IP addresses to run the Ansible playbook against, as follows:

```
resource "null_resource" "Ansible4Ubuntu" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 20;ansible-playbook -i '${element(azurerm_network_interface.unic.*.private_ip_address, count.index)}', vmlinux-playbook.yml"
```

I have also tried:

```
resource "null_resource" "Ansible4Ubuntu" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 20;ansible-playbook -i '${azurerm_network_interface.unic.private_ip_address}', vmlinux-playbook.yml"
```

They both work fine with the first VM only and ignores the rest. I have also tried with `count.index+1 and self.private_ip_address`, but no luck.

Actual result: TF provides the private IP of only the first VM to Ansible.

Expected result: TF to provide a list of all private IPs to Ansible so that it can run the playbook against all of them.

PS: I am also looking at using the TF's remote_state data structure, but seems like the state file contains IPs from previous builds as well, making it hard to extract the ones good for the current build.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Asghar

Comment: I feel like the actual problem here is that the `local-exec` is only going to execute once per block and not once per resource iteration, which is why you are only getting an execution on the first ip address. A better way of doing this which would also solve your problem might be to use a Terraform `template` to output all of the ip addresses into an Ansible hosts file which you can then leverage instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt said, the null_resource just run one time, so it just works fine with the first VM and ignores the rest. You need to configure triggers for the null_resource with the NIC list to make it run multiple times. Sample code like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "Ansible4Ubuntu" {

    triggers = {
      network_interface_ids = "${join(",", azurerm_network_interface.unic.*.id)}"
    }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sleep 20;ansible-playbook -i '${join(" ", azurerm_network_interface.unic.*.private_ip_address)}, vmlinux-playbook.yml"
  }

}
```

You can change something in it as you want. For information, see [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html).

Comment: Thanks Charles. The code works like a charm with a minor change (a comma within the quotation) in the command: 
     command = "sleep 20;ansible-playbook -i ${join(",", azurerm_network_interface.cnic.*.private_ip_address)} vmlinux-playbook.yml"

Comment: Just tried the provisioning for a single VM and Ansible reported inventory error: null_resource.DataDisks4Ubuntu (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "sleep 10 ; ansible-playbook -i 100.96.85.4 datadisk-playbook.yml"] null_resource.DataDisks4Ubuntu (local-exec): [WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/linuxadm/Automation/Terraform/dev-both-works/100.96.85.4 as an inventory source null_resource.DataDisks4Ubuntu (local-exec): [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available.... I guess a comma has to be present at the end of the IP address to make it work?